# Passing variables into file location

Tags: php

Can someone please show me what is wrong here and please explain, I cant seem to get this to work. I get the following error message;

> PHP Warning:  file_exists() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in
> /code/system/library/system.inc on line 29

```
$Language = 'US';
$PageName = 'Home';

if(file_exists('code/system/content/' . $Language, $PageName . '.inc')){

do something here....

}
```

Comment: You have a comma between `'code/system/content/' . $Language` and `$PageName . '.inc'` so it's 2 arguments. I suspect the comma is a typo for `.`

Comment: What is the pathname you're trying to create?

Comment: code/system/content/USHome.inc

Comment: Removed coma tried every way I know and still no luck?

Comment: Just change the comma to period. Just like you have between `'code/system/content/'` and `$Language`.

Comment: works fine with just one variable

Comment: You can also use string interpolation: `"code/system/content/$Language$PageName.inc"`

Answer (score 0):

Got it with 'code/system/content/' . $Language . $PageName . '.inc'